# Are (complete) 2-Segal spaces the same as Span-enriched infinity categories?

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, enriched-category-theory

The question is basically in the title. More generally, I would like to know if this, or any reasonable variant of it, is true. Or perhaps, to understand better the gap between 2-Segal spaces and Span-enriched $\infty$-categories.

#### Background

2-Segal spaces (see e.g. Dyckerhoff and Kapranov-s [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3563.pdf)) are usually informally described as $\infty$-categories with multi-valued composition. This notion seems to be most naturally encoded by enrichment over the $\infty$-category of [spans](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span) of spaces and this interpretation is mentioned both in the [nLab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+Segal+space) and in this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279478/the-category-theory-of-span-enriched-categories-2-segal-spaces) by Tim Campion. Dyckerhoff and Kapranov prove something of this sort for 2-Segal *sets*, but for 2-Segal spaces there are instead some involved constructions with algebras in the $(\infty,2)$-category of BiSpans, which I am not sure how they relate to enrichment over Span.

It seems important to note that for 1-Segal spaces, which are "category objects" in spaces, we do need to impose *completeness* to get a model for usual $\infty$-categories. It therefore seems reasonable that general 2-Segal spaces encode "multi-compoisiontal category objects" and only after imposing some completeness condition, we might hope to get Span-enriched $\infty$-categories. In the above mentioned paper there is a definition of completeness for 2-Segal spaces (combine def 9.3.2 for completeness of (co)Segal fibrations and def 9.3.4 for the Hall (co)Segal fibration associated to a 2-Segal space). This might or might not be the relevant notion of completeness and I admit that I don't have a good understanding of it.

Another issue is the comparison of the *morphisms* on both sides. As pointed out by Tim Campion in his question, morphisms of 2-Segal spaces might need to correspond to Span-enriched functors which have actual maps (and not just spans) between the corresponding mapping spaces.

Comment: There's some redundancy in the links -- I believe I wrote the relevant portions of the nlab page :). That's a very good point about the subtlety of completeness -- it's quite possible that I've jumped to conclusions and the story is more complicated than one might naively imagine...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is now [a theorem of Walker Stern](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.06671).